# Negative Lookahead pattern which matches no matter where it is in a string

Tags: java, regex

This is linked to [Ignoring case for a whole pattern of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16809700/1197747) but it is a different question.

I was wondering if there was anyway to ignore the beginning of a string or if a Negative Lookahead only works from left too right and needs a starting point? Every thing I have tried seems to always find a match.

The current pattern I am using is

```
(?i)^(?!pack ?station|paket ?station).*$
```

This works fine for "packstation foo bar", but if I want to match "foo packstation bar" then it does not work.

The string can only be a max of 26 characters and if it contains the strings below then I would like to match it.

- packstation - ( packstation | Packstation | PACKSTATION )
- pack station - ( pack station | Pack station | pack Station | Pack Station | PACK STATION )
- paketstation - ( paketstation | Paketstation | PAKETSTATION )
- paket station - ( paket station | Paket station| paket Station| Paket Station | PAKET STATION )

Comment: Why *negative* lookahead if you want to match it?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but I thought you used negative if its not allowed to contain the matched pattern? My issue is I only wanted to pass in a pattern with out doing anything else. This pattern only accepts a string that does not contain the strings mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

```
(?i)^(?=.*(pack ?station|paket ?station)).{1,26}$
```

You were missing `.*` in lookahead.

Also if you want to match it,using **positive lookahead** would be more clearer..

Comment: I have a question. It works, but why? Is it because the .* in the lookahead is greedy, attempts to consume the whole string, then continually drops one character and tries to match the lookahead at every possible point?

Comment: @Patashu with `.*` it eats every character in string.i.e it goes at the end..then it backtracks 1 by 1 to match `(pack(et)? ?station)`..

Comment: It doesn't consume the input if it means *not* matching

Comment: (Currently, this doesn't exclude `Paketstation`. You could make the `c` optional at the expense of false positive matches like `Pakstation`, or reintroduce the original alternation.

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes..indeed sir..you are right..edited the ans..thanks